# Making my code more Robust for Appium Android Automation

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I am using JAVA for Android Automation of an App. I have written all the Success test cases and they are working fine. I wanted to know how can I add negative cases in the same code like if a test case fails at some point instead of stopping the appium would exit that specific test case and move to the next test case.

Currently my code is in one class that contains all the success Test cases that are executed one after another. The appium stops if one of the test case fails at any point as it is not able to identify the next command.

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: you can use testng framework in your project. You must handle the exception properly in order to make the test run even if some test failed.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I will definitely look into testing frameworks to add to my JAVA code to make it robust.

Comment: You can learn testng from https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: Assuming you're already using JUnit or TestNG, consider adding a BDD framework like Cucumber or JBehave which will allow you to write Features/Stories which contain individual test scenarios in Gherkin syntax.  This allows you to modularize your tests in plain English and each test scenario can be tested and reported pass/fail and it will move on to the next test scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bill but I am currently not using JUnit or TestNG, I will definitely look into using one of these tools to help in automation.

Comment: I would suggest you to use TestNG over JUnit as it is much robust and the tests are also very clean.